# '2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server' from browser

Tags: centos, mysql

I have created a CentOS 9 droplet on DigitalOcean and a separate MySQL 8 Database. I can connect to this database from the droplet's console as well as from the terminal on my Mac. I can also run a python script from my terminal smoothly which retrieves data from this database. But I can't run the script in the web browser on my Mac, because I receive this error:

*2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db-mysql-......ondigitalocean.com:25060' (13)*

Here's some info:
Both the droplet and the database are in the same account and in the same region.
There is no VPC network set up.
I added the droplet's IP address and my Mac's IP as a Trusted Source in the database settings. This should be fine as I already wrote I can reach the db from my Mac.
The admin file's order of priority is:

```
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

And /etc/my.cnf is the correct config file as per

```
sudo find / -type f -name "my.cnf" -o -name "mysqld.cnf" 2>/dev/null
/etc/my.cnf
```

The /etc/my.cnf includes only a few explanatory lines. `/etc/mysql` folder doesn't even exist. What I have is `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf`. But even after adding `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to any or both of `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf` I still get the same error. I even added `port = 25060` to `/etc/my.cnf` (I can't add this to `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf` because then I run into error restarting mysql.

Contents of `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
  GNU nano 5.6.1                                 /etc/my.cnf                                            
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 25060
```

Contents of `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf`

```
  GNU nano 5.6.1                        /etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf                        Modified  
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Checking firewall settings:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --state
Running

sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 25060/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But:

```
nmap -p 25060 localhost
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
25060/tcp closed unknown
```

While

```
nmap -p 3306 localhost
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Maybe this is the error but I can't seem to open the port:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=25060/tcp --permanent
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 25060:tcp
success
```

You may also notice that there is no [mysqld] part in /etc/my.cnf. This is because if I add this, I can't restart mysql:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysqld.service" for details
```

Though in these logs I couldn't find anything important, I was able to create a custom my.cnf in another folder, and finally restart mysql but even that did nothing.